# What is the difference between Collections.sort() and other traditional sorting algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Say we have an ArrayList arr which equals `{1, 3, 2, 5, 4}` and we want to sort it in numerical order.  We could call `Collections.sort(arr)` and sort it that way, or we could use another traditional sorting algorithm, such as quick sort or bubble sort.

My question is, what is the difference between calling `Collections.sort()` and just writing our own sorting algorithm using traditional sorting methods?

Comment: Yes; `Collections.sort()` is certainly easier than writing a sorting algorithm.

Comment: Define _better_. Define _easier to implement_. The javadoc of that method explains exactly what it does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I guess all I really want to know is what the difference is.  I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: You mean which is easier to implement between calling `Collections.sort` or writing your own implementation of Bubble Sort? Really? The Java JDK was designed and written by some of the world's finest programmers. Bubble sort is the worst example of a sorting algorithm you could come up with. You tell me...

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I understand that.  That is why I am asking about the difference.  Why not just use Collections.sort() all the time instead of writing our own?

Comment: You will never write your own. Unless you are able to use a non-comparison sort for your particular problem - this is rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting methods built into the Java standard libraries should be used for the vast majority of cases. They are general purpose, efficient and reliable. There are rare instances when a custom sorting mechanism is required.

An example of a case requiring a custom sorting mechanism might be a very large collection that is known to be 'almost' sorted: it can be more efficient to find and move those few entries than to re-sort the collection. Note, however, that this doesn't mean you need to write your own custom sorting mechanism - [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), for instance, is designed for subsets of this use case. There is likely to be a reliable mechanism available in a third party library for just about any situation you can come up with.

Unless you are writing applications dealing with very large amounts of data in an unusual domain then `Collections.sort` is all you will need.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer.

Comment: Your example is **wrong**. TimSort is specifically designed to detect presorted data and deal with is as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how does that make my answer wrong? TimSort is a good example of a custom sorting mechanism. In fact that's exactly why I chose that example - it's a well known use case for which  `Collections.sort` is not optimised. In case there's any confusion I'll add a reference to it to my answer.

Comment: It goes beyond this, though. One of the big things after you're doing with introductory programming, data structures, and algorithms classes is you stop reinventing the wheel and instead use the language's standard library, third-party libraries, and frameworks. But make no mistake, what all those are doing under the hood is the same thing you learned in school. On of the biggest things I've learned is that what's going on behind the scenes is rarely magic, and the implementation will vaguely resemble how you'd do it.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Agreed. I know some programming students question why they are learning to build linked lists or sorting algorithms when they are all built into modern languages. My view is that these are still all good things to understand and practice on before learning to rely on what's already there.

Comment: @sprinter: they're definitely valuable. Knowing how they work internally goes a long way in making the right choices in algorithms and data structures.

Comment: sprinter and @DavidEhrmann, thank you for these very useful answers, as they target my original question precisely.  That is the main thing I was wondering about, regarding the difference between using standard libs and custom made algorithms.  It makes me happy to know that the standard libs are generally the way to go, but that it is useful to understand what is going on under the hood for a more comprehensive learning of the language.

Comment: @sprinter erm - `Collections.sort` uses TimSort... Hence the wrongness.